# Floating action button start up animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have been looking around online for a while, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I have a floating action button that I have *working* already. It shows up and is clickable etc, but at this point has nothing wired up to it. Before I go any further I want to know how to make it animate on startup.

On the material design page for FAB it shows like a sprout type animation where it comes from the correct location, but animates to its intended size. [Found here](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsWVlROHRlam9FMUU/components-buttons-fab-behavior_01_xhdpi_012.webm).

Any info is appreciated.

Comment: it's build-in animation use : floatButton.hide() (or show);

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the `Behavior` class inside of `FloatingActionButton`. For example this is how the enter animation is implemented:

```
private void animateIn(FloatingActionButton button) {
    button.setVisibility(0);
    if(VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        ViewCompat.animate(button).scaleX(1.0F).scaleY(1.0F).alpha(1.0F).setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR).withLayer().setListener((ViewPropertyAnimatorListener)null).start();
    } else {
        Animation anim = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), anim.fab_in);
        anim.setDuration(200L);
        anim.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
        button.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey again! So would this be placed inside the `onCreateView()` of the `FloatingActionButtonFragment` class? Or would it be like `behavior.animateIn(FAB)`? not sure what context this would be used in

Comment: Yes, but you probably want the animation to play only the first time when `savedInstanceState == null`.

Comment: I can't find `animateIn` in the api. Mind linking me or editing your answer to reflect how I can implement it. I found the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` class but there is [nothing about animation in there](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html).

Comment: Its not a public api, thats why i pointed you to it. Internally it is used in conjunction with CoordinatorLayout. To make use of it you would need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `AnimationUtils` here. Here is an easy tutorial: [Android Animations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm)